# why is my UPDATE with a subquery failing?

Tags: mysql

```
UPDATE survey_results_activities_temp
SET risk_p=titles.risk_p
WHERE employee_title= 
(SELECT CASE 
                 WHEN t.risk='low' THEN  100
                 WHEN t.risk='medium' THEN  50
                 ELSE 0
              END as risk_p 
        FROM titles t WHERE t.title=employee_title)
```

I have two tables. Titles has a field called title and also a field called risk. I am trying to set a field in survey_results_activities_temp with 0, 50 or 100 for ALL of the rows. Each row of it has a field called employee_title, but I am getting this error from mySQL:

> #1054 - Unknown column 'titles.risk_p' in 'field list'

Comment: It seems unlikely that title would ever equal risk_p. Please review update syntax here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html and publish table defintions , sample data and expected outcome as text in the question

Answer (score 0):

PLease remove  "as risk_p"

```
UPDATE survey_results_activities_temp
SET risk_p=titles.risk_p
WHERE employee_title= 
(SELECT CASE 
                 WHEN t.risk='low' THEN  100
                 WHEN t.risk='medium' THEN  50
                 ELSE 0
              END 
        FROM titles t WHERE t.title=employee_title)
```

Comment: Thanks. That causes this error: Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'titles.risk_p' in 'field list'

UPDATE survey_results_activities_temp SET risk_p=titles.risk_p WHERE employee_title= (SELECT CASE WHEN t.risk='low' THEN 100 WHEN t.risk='medium' THEN 50 ELSE 0 END FROM titles t WHERE t.title=employee_title)

Filename: models/MyModel.php

Line Number: 427

Comment: I hope I was able to solve your issue. Cheers